# Program to find the maximum product of two numbers in a given integer array

Tags: java

Kindly help me with the underlying program as I am stuck. I'm a newbie programmer.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Source  
{ 
  static int maxProduct(int arr[]) {
        int n = arr.length ;
        if (n < 2) 
        { 
            System.out.println("NA"); 
            return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        } 
        int a = arr[0];
        int b = arr[1];
        for(int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
          for (int j = i+1; j<n; j++) {
            if (arr[i]*arr[j] > arr[0]*arr[1]) {
              a = arr[i];
              b = arr[j];
            }
          }
        }
        return maxProduct;
     }
  }
  
  public static void main(String[] args)  
  { 
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int size = s.nextInt();
    int[] arr = new int[size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      arr[i] = s.nextInt();
    }
    int answer = maxProduct(arr); 
    System.out.print(answer);
  } 
}
```

Comment: You didn't describe what the program is actually doing or show attempts to debug it.

Answer (score 2):

You should change

```
if (arr[i]*arr[j] > arr[0]*arr[1])
```

to

```
if (arr[i]*arr[j] > a * b)
```

Since `arr[0]*arr[1]` is just the original max product, so you shouldn't be comparing against it.

Also note that your solution is not as efficient as it can be, since you are using a nested loop, which requires O(n^2) running time.

You can achieve linear (O(n)) running time if you use the fact that the max product is either the product of the two highest positive values or the product of the two lowest negative values. This means that if you find these 4 numbers, which can be done with a single loop, you'll find the max product.

Comment: The usual recommendation: think before code … +1!